# How to declare an inner class of a C++ DLL which is called by multiple threads without exporting the class

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am making a c++ dll which I exports a simple class from it. In the target program I make multiple objects of that class in multiple threads. I have another class inside the dll which is not exported nor declared in the exported class. I declared the hidden class in a cpp file (which has the functions in it) and initialized it in constructor of the main class. The code below, demostrate my explaination:

```
#define DllExport __declspec( dllexport ) 

class class_1
{
public:
    DllExport class_1(); 
    DllExport ~class_1();
    DllExport int function_1(unsigned char* input);
};
```

Above code was in "mydll.h" file that I export. In a "mydll.cpp" file I defined function_1 and also declared another class like this:

```
class class_2
{
public:
    class_2(); 
    ~class_2();
    int function_2(int a);
};
```

class_2 will be initialize in the constructor of class_1. When in the target project I make multiple objects of class_1 and use them in different threads, the class_2 object is "common" and when 2 threads are using class_1 objects, They access to only one class_2 object, simultaneously so the program crashes.

Where and how should I declare and initialize class_2 in the dll for avoiding threads conflicting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Options:

1. Make your instance of `class_2` `thread_local`.  One will exist per-thread.  This can act surprising if your `class_1` accesses `class_2` instance in different threads.
2. Add a `pImpl` to `class_1` that points to an opaque `class_2`.

So:

```
class class_2;
class class_1 {
  std::unique_ptr<class_2> pImpl;
public:
  DllExport class_1(); 
  DllExport ~class_1();
  DllExport int function_1(unsigned char* input);
};
```

As `~unique_ptr<class_2>` is only called within `~class1`, this is safe.

Comment: Thanks for helping. Now I'm confused how should I pass arguments to the constructor of class_2 (the pimpl class)?

Comment: I used make_unique but it gives error. I wrote sth like this: class_1::class_1(const wchar_t* m_File) : pImpl(std::make_unique<class_2>(m_File)) ?!!

Comment: @meisam try asking another question; comments do not permit the context to solve errors like that